How do I change the figure size when working with a function that outputs a Matplotlib Axes object?
I am working with a function that outputs a matplotlib Axes object, which shows a graph as well. The function is from the PointPats module, part of PySAL, specifically the QStatistic.plot() function. The graph that is being output is extremely compressed and I need to change the dimensions of the graph; however, I am not sure how to do that when working with just an axes object. Ideally I would like to add the axes to a figure, but I'm not sure how to do that with a standalone axes object.
I have tried to use the plt.figure.add_axes() function but get the following error message: The "Axes must have been created in the present figure".

Since you have the axes, you can get hold of the figure it’s already on with fig = ax.get_figure().  You can then update the figure’s size with fig.set_size_inches().

AFAICT every Matplotlib Artist has the attribute .figure, that references the Figure containing the Artist itself.
The implication is that you can change the Figure dimensions afterwards
ax = YourLibraryFunctionThatReturnsAnAxes(...)
ax.figure.set_figwidth(inches_width)
ax.figure.set_figheight(inches_height)

and of course you can, in the same manner, change every single aspect of the Figure.
